# Python / django.db: How to create a generic class without hardcoded Meta.db_table?

Tags: django, database, oop

I have a class using django.db as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class myClass(models.Model):
    "My class"
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_table'

    field1 = models.CharField()
    # more fields here

    def some_function(self):
        return "hello"
```

I'd like to turn this into a generic class that does not have "my_table" hardcoded, so that I can use it in some way such as:

```
class GenericClass(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = None

# genericClass properties and methods here

class myClass(GenericClass):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).Meta.db_table = 'my_table'
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, this gives me the following error (using Python 2.7 / Django 1.11):

```
Local field u'id' in class 'myClass' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'GenericClass'
```

Is there any way to create a generic class that extends django.db.models.Model, that supports a non-default database table name without hardcoding Meta.db_table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are asking is a Django equivalent of AbstractSuperClass / SuperClass.

If what you want is AbstractSuperClass for django model you can define it like

```
class AbstractModel(models.Model):
   field1 = ...
   field2 = ...
   ...
   class Meta:
      abstract = True


class SubClassModel(models.Model):
    field3 = ...
    class Meta:
        db_table=sub_class_db_table
```

Your AbstractModel won't have a database table. It simply acts as a superclass to store common fields (and even you can define common functions).

If you `DESC` your sub_class_db_table, you will find `field1`, `field2`, `field3`.

See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) for more details.

If you want to create a db_table hierarchy itself (`field1` and `field2` will be in the `super_class_table` and `field3` will be in `sub_class_table`), you can use [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). This will be useful especially if there is a service-contract scenario - A team or a module owns common functionality including the db_table, its maintenance. But this way is less commonly used.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for the scope of this question. Now to just get the abstract class methods working properly...